# Limiting the number of records from mysqldump?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to load a small sample of records from a large database into a test database.

How do you tell mysqldump to only give you n records out of 8 million?

Thanks

Answer (score 245):

As skaffman says, use the **--where** option:

```
mysqldump --opt --where="1 limit 1000000" database
```

Of course, that would give you the first million rows from every table.

Comment: What does the "1" before limit do?

Comment: @Phob:  The --where option is basically appended to a query of the form `SELECT * from table WHERE `, so in this case you get `SELECT * from table WHERE 1 limit 1000000`.  Without the 1, you would have an invalid query.  Specifying 1 for a where clause (since 1 is always true) simply selects all records.

Comment: Wow, what a hack.  So you can basically SQL inject yourself this way.

Comment: Does this maintain all foreign key integrities? If not, is there a way to do that?

Comment: Is there a way to get the *last* 1,000,000 rows, i.e. the most recently added ones?

Comment: Thanks!

Additionally, you can use:  

`mysqldump --opt --where="1 limit 1000000 offset 1000000" --no-create-info database`  

to get the second page of 1 million records.   Make sure to use the _--no-create-info_ flag on pages other than the first to only dump the data and leave off the _create table_ stuff.

Comment: Looks like `--opt` isn't necessary. From the manpages: "Because the --opt option is enabled by default, you only specify its converse, the --skip-opt to turn off several default settings."

Answer (score 66):

If you want to get `n` records from a specific table you can do something like this:

```
mysqldump --opt --where="1 limit 1000000" database table > dump.sql
```

This will dump the first `1000000` rows from the table named `table` into the file `dump.sql`.

Answer (score 15):

As the default order is ASC which is rarely what you want in this situation, you need to have a proper database design to make DESC work out of the box. If all your tables have ONE primary key column with the same name (natural or surrogate) you can easily dump the n latest records using:

```
mysqldump --opt --where="1 ORDER BY id DESC limit 1000000" --all-databases > dump.sql
```

This is a perfect reason to why you should always name your PK's *id* and avoid composite PK's, even in association tables (use surrogate keys instead).

Comment: Do this (name id and avoid composite PK's) and you'll need to ignore relational database theory.

Comment: Actually, if you design your database following the best practices of relational database, defining your PK's based on data and entity, you can use --option --where="1 LIMIT 10000" for example. Without ORDER BY, this will work because MySQL will order in natural manner, what is equivalent to say that it will follow the PK's index order. Then, all FK of related tables will have only data that exists in their reference's table because the order will be the same.

Comment: The use of ID's is a true plague of many developers. Having ID's like PK's is the same of doesn't having PK's. Your integrity was go to hole because, in most of the cases, an auto increment number doesn't have nothing to do with the entity data.

Comment: @mpoletto  --where="1 LIMIT 10000" will only pick the 10000 first entries. The whole point of my answer was to show how you would solve getting the latest X entries, which is usually what you want. I also do not understand what naming conventions has to do with "ignoring relational database theory", I think you missunderstood my answer. Most popular ORMs like EF, Django ORM, etc. default to and advise "id" for PK-columns, since it is redundant to say users.user_id instead of just users.id.

Comment: when you say that there is a "perfect reason to why you should always name you PK's id and avoid composite PK's" you are ignoring relational database theory. Your argument about "most popular ORMs" isn't valid because this ORMs need tables with IDs to work.

Comment: @mpoletto And how am I ignoring RBDMS theory by saying that PKs should be called simply id instead of i.e. user_id?

Comment: When you say to avoid composite keys. You don't avoid keys when you design a relational model, you define keys because you need, don't matter if they are composite keys or not. You don't design a model based on what an ORMs needs. Not all models fit to use surrogate keys. But, unfortunately, this is very common practice between programmers.

Comment: Thanks you very much, this is really what I searching for

Comment: You can also `ORDER BY 1 DESC` if your ID columns aren't named consistently but are the first logical column defined in the table.

Comment: is there a way through mysql internals to get the most recent N updated rows?

Comment: @awm set an updated_at column and sort on it instead

Answer (score 7):

mysqldump can be given a SQL query to execute, from which it will take the data for the dump. You can then use the "limit X" clause in your query to restrict the number of rows.

Comment: Really? How can you give mysqldump a query? I can't find it in the documentation.

Comment: @RobertMikes Example: `mysqldump --skip-lock-tables test parent --where="exists(select * from child where parent_id=parent.id)"`

Comment: @Dexter OK, agreed, you can limit the number of records when querying a particular table. Which might be enough to cover the use case that the OP asked about. But you can't give a full query to mysqldump, where you would control the fields that are selected from multiple tables... Well, as a workaround you could always create a table and fill it with derived data using INSERT INTO SELECT, then dump that table...