# Mysql take dump of some portion like 10-20 % of whole database

Tags: mysql, database, database-dump

I know that to take database dump I can ignore some tables.
but I want to take the dump of all table with some percentage of data like 20% 40% because the whole dump is too big.
here is my normal dump query.

```
mysqldump -h dburl -u user -p password --databases dbname > dbname.sql
```

I am not looking for specific OS and using Linux Ubuntu.

Comment: You can use combination of `mysqldump -h dburl -u user -p password --no-data --databases dbname > dbname.schema.sql` to get DB schema, then a sequence of `SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE` statements to dump tables data with filtering. And `LOAD DATA INFILE` statements to load data back. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select-into.html for details.

Comment: The problem you are likely to have is making your subset respect constraints, without which it will surely be fairly unusable in practice. I would suggest googling for open source tools aimed specifically for this purpose - these do clearly exist,

Comment: You should probably tag the OS you are working on which helps scripting people.

Comment: @MandyShaw Yes That is bigger problem with current options, It would  be awesome if you give some good name or links for tools Thanks.

Comment: I haven't tried it myself but this looks like the sort of thing: https://github.com/18F/rdbms-subsetter

Answer (score 4):

The [*80-20 rule*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareto_principle) says that the smallest 80% of the tables will probably consume only 20% of the space.  So have one mysqldump for them.

Then have more mysqldump(s) for each remaining table smaller than 20% of the space.

Finally, any big tables need the `--where` option mentioned by Nambu14.  Or you could *try* the kludge of saying `--where="true LIMIT 20000,10000"` to sneak an `OFFSET` and `LIMIT` in.  (See one of the comments on https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html )  *But* do not allow writes to the table while doing that -- it could lead to extra/missing records.

Or you could adapt chunking techniques as discussed [*here*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/deletebig) .  This avoids the extra/missing problem and avoids the `LIMIT` kludge.  With luck, you can hard code the range values needed for ranges like this `--where="my_pk >= 'def' AND my_pk < 'mno'"`

Don't forget to deal with Triggers, Stored routine, Views, etc.

Answer (score 2):

There's a similar [question open](https://stackoverflow.com/q/135835/3661126). With the **--where** option you can limit the amount of records included in the **mysqldump** ([official documentation here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_where)), but this option applies for every table in the database.

Another way is to give the command a sql script to run and prepare the data in that script, this will work as a pseudo ETL pipeline.

Comment: Thanks, That kinda solves the problem and making a script doesn't sounds good will wait for some more time to see something better.

Comment: Glad to be helpful! :)

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want to avoid making a script, one quick solution is to use the `--where` option for mysqldump.

```
mysqldump --opt --where="1 limit 1000" myschema
```

This will limit dumps to 1000 rows - obviously adjust to your size restrictions.

You can follow this up with an offset dump to get the next 1000 - a small adjustment is needed so the table is not recreated.

```
mysqldump --opt --where="1 limit 1000 offset 1000" --no-create-info myschema
```

You can mix this up further, say you want only 40% of all data, from randomly selected rows:

```
mysqldump --opt --where="1 having rand() < 0.40" myschema
```